# How could I draw this table?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I have been trying to recreate this table using multi row but have been having no luck.

Basically, column 'e' applies to both 'x' and 'y'; all others (a/b/c/d) have their own values.

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrPGq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome . What have you done so far? Does [How to split cell text into multiline in table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346562/124842) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is pretty much what you want. It uses the `\multirow` command to spread the content over multiple rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
  & A & B & C & D & E \\ \hline
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \multirow{ 2}{*}{5} \\
y & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Renders to:

[image: resulting table]

Adapted from [How to use \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73283/how-to-use-multirow).

Answer (score 1):

I propose this semantically-oriented variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ multirow, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\toprule
  & A & B & C & D & E \\
  \midrule
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \multirow{ 2}{*}{$ \mathllap{\begin{rcases}\\[1ex]\end{rcases}\ }$5} \\
y & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]